# @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) not able to catch HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jetty

> [WARNING] Could not send response error 500: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException

I'm writing exception handlers using @ControllerAdvice & @ExceptionHandler in spring. I have a generic exception handler as below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);
//other ExceptionHandlers to catch specific exceptions

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorMessage handleException(Exception ex) {

        //other code
        logger.error("Exception in API", ex);
        //other code
    }
}
```

Why i'm not able to catch exception in 'handleException'?, why spring say it's a warning not as an error?

Update:
In DAO layer because of wrong-input for an operation, hibernate throws HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException. Yet, why my GlobalExceptionHandler(Global Exception Class) is not able to catch this ?

Comment: Where the HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException is thrown in your code?

Comment: Maybe the `@Controller` class that throws the exception also has `@ExceptionHandler` method ? If yes, the exception will be handled by it first before handled by `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: @KenChan: I’m not handling exception inside Controller, intention is to handle all at global level.